# How to properly extract a method in Java intelliJ?

Tags: java, methods, 2d, extract, platform

***EDIT***

I am trying to create a 2D platform-game in Java. I have a Player-class that has an update()-method:

```
public class Player {
...
...
...

    public void update(TileBlock[][] tb, ArrayList<MovingBlock> movingBlocks) {

        // checkBlockCollision(TileBlock[][] tb)
        // checkMovingBlockCollision(ArrayList<MovingBlock> movingBlocks)

        // Bounds for collision
        int x1 = (int) (x + width + GameState.xOffset);
        int y1 = (int) (y + height + GameState.yOffset);
        int x2 = (int) (x + GameState.xOffset);
        int y2 = (int) (y + GameState.yOffset);

        // Tile Block Collision
        for (TileBlock[] tileBlocks : tb) {
            for (int x = 0; x < tb[0].length; x++) {
                if (tileBlocks[x].getID() == 1) {

                    // Right collision
                    if (Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x1, y2 - 2), tileBlocks[x]) ||
                            Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x1, y1 - 1), tileBlocks[x])) {
                        right = false;
                    }

                    // Left collision
                    if (Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x2 - 1, y2 + 2), tileBlocks[x]) ||
                            Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x2 - 1, y1 - 1), tileBlocks[x])) {
                        left = false;
                    }

                    // Top Collision
                    if (Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x2 + 1, y2), tileBlocks[x]) ||
                            Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x1 - 2, y2), tileBlocks[x])) {
                        jumping = false;
                        falling = true;
                    }

                    // Bottom collision
                    if (Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x2 + 2, y1 + 1), tileBlocks[x]) ||
                            Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x1 - 2, y1 + 1), tileBlocks[x])) {
                        y = tileBlocks[x].getY() - height - GameState.yOffset;
                        falling = false;
                        topCollision = true;
                    }
                    if (!topCollision && !jumping) {
                        falling = true;

                    }
                } else if (tileBlocks[x].getID() == 2) {

                    // Right collision
                    if (Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x1, y2 - 2), tileBlocks[x]) ||
                            Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x1, y1 - 1), tileBlocks[x])) {
                        reachedGoal = true;
                    }

                    // Left collision
                    if (Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x2 - 1, y2 + 2), tileBlocks[x]) ||
                            Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x2 - 1, y1 - 1), tileBlocks[x])) {
                        reachedGoal = true;
                    }

                    // Top Collision
                    if (Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x2 + 1, y2), tileBlocks[x]) ||
                            Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x1 - 2, y2), tileBlocks[x])) {
                        reachedGoal = true;
                    }

                    // Bottom collision
                    if (Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x2 + 2, y1 + 1), tileBlocks[x]) ||
                            Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x1 - 2, y1 + 1), tileBlocks[x])) {
                        reachedGoal = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Moving Block Collision
        if (movingBlocks != null && !movingBlocks.isEmpty()){
            for (MovingBlock movingBlock : movingBlocks) {
                if (movingBlock.getID() != 0) {
                    // Right collision
                    if (Collision.playerMovingBlock(new Point(x1, y2 - 2), movingBlock) ||
                            Collision.playerMovingBlock(new Point(x1, y1 - 1), movingBlock)) {
                        right = false;
                    }
                    // Left collision
                    if (Collision.playerMovingBlock(new Point(x2 - 1, y2 + 2), movingBlock) ||
                            Collision.playerMovingBlock(new Point(x2 - 1, y1 - 1), movingBlock)) {
                        left = false;
                    }

                    // Top Collision
                    if (Collision.playerMovingBlock(new Point(x2 + 1, y2), movingBlock) ||
                            Collision.playerMovingBlock(new Point(x1 - 2, y2), movingBlock)) {
                        jumping = false;
                        falling = true;
                    }

                    // Bottom collision
                    if (Collision.playerMovingBlock(new Point(x2 + 2, y1 + 1), movingBlock) ||
                            Collision.playerMovingBlock(new Point(x1 - 2, y1 + 1), movingBlock)) {
                        y = movingBlock.getY() - height - GameState.yOffset;
                        falling = false;
                        topCollision = true;

                        // Move the player the same amount the block is moving
                        GameState.xOffset += movingBlock.getMove();
                    } else {
                        if (!topCollision && !jumping) {
                            falling = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        topCollision = false;
        double moveSpeed = 2.5;

        if (right) {
            GameState.xOffset += moveSpeed;    // Move the tile-block to the left because the player is moving right
        }
         if (left){
             GameState.xOffset -= moveSpeed;    // Move the tile-block to the right because the player is moving left
         }
         if (jumping){
             GameState.yOffset -= currentJumpSpeed;
             currentJumpSpeed -= 0.1;           // Jump is slowing down at 0.1 pixel per call to update()
             if (currentJumpSpeed <= 0){
                 currentJumpSpeed = startSpeed;
                 jumping = false;
                 falling = true;
             }
         }
         if (falling){
             GameState.yOffset += currentFallSpeed;
             // Fall-speed
             double maxFallSpeed = 5;
             if (currentFallSpeed < maxFallSpeed){
                 currentFallSpeed += 0.1;
             }
         }
         if (!falling) { currentFallSpeed = 0.1; }  // So we fall again without going too fast in the start

        // Player/Enemy collision
        if (Collision.PECollision() && !invincible) {
            health--;
            invincible = true;
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        if (invincible) {
            int deathDuration = 2000; //in milliseconds
            long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            if (duration > deathDuration){
                invincible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code works, but `update()` is very big. So I am trying to extract the two collision-methods, so that I only call them in `update()`. But when I try to change the code above to this:

```
public void update(TileBlock[][] tb, ArrayList<MovingBlock> movingBlocks) {

    checkBlockCollision(tb);
    checkMovingBlockCollision(movingBlocks);

    topCollision = false;
    double moveSpeed = 2.5;

    if (right) {
        GameState.xOffset += moveSpeed;    // Move the tile-block to the left because the player is moving right
    }
     if (left){
         GameState.xOffset -= moveSpeed;    // Move the tile-block to the right because the player is moving left
     }
     if (jumping){
         GameState.yOffset -= currentJumpSpeed;
         currentJumpSpeed -= 0.1;           // Jump is slowing down at 0.1 pixel per call to update()
         if (currentJumpSpeed <= 0){
             currentJumpSpeed = startSpeed;
             jumping = false;
             falling = true;
         }
     }
     if (falling){
         GameState.yOffset += currentFallSpeed;
         // Fall-speed
         double maxFallSpeed = 5;
         if (currentFallSpeed < maxFallSpeed){
             currentFallSpeed += 0.1;
         }
     }
     if (!falling) { currentFallSpeed = 0.1; }  // So we fall again without going too fast in the start

    // Player/Enemy collision
    if (Collision.PECollision() && !invincible) {
        health--;
        invincible = true;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    if (invincible) {
        int deathDuration = 2000; //in milliseconds
        long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        if (duration > deathDuration){
            invincible = false;
        }
    }
}

private void checkMovingBlockCollision(ArrayList<MovingBlock> movingBlocks) {
    // Moving Block Collision
    if (movingBlocks != null && !movingBlocks.isEmpty()){
        for (MovingBlock movingBlock : movingBlocks) {
            if (movingBlock.getID() != 0) {
                // Right collision
                if (Collision.playerMovingBlock(new Point(x1, y2 - 2), movingBlock) ||
                        Collision.playerMovingBlock(new Point(x1, y1 - 1), movingBlock)) {
                    right = false;
                }
                // Left collision
                if (Collision.playerMovingBlock(new Point(x2 - 1, y2 + 2), movingBlock) ||
                        Collision.playerMovingBlock(new Point(x2 - 1, y1 - 1), movingBlock)) {
                    left = false;
                }

                // Top Collision
                if (Collision.playerMovingBlock(new Point(x2 + 1, y2), movingBlock) ||
                        Collision.playerMovingBlock(new Point(x1 - 2, y2), movingBlock)) {
                    jumping = false;
                    falling = true;
                }

                // Bottom collision
                if (Collision.playerMovingBlock(new Point(x2 + 2, y1 + 1), movingBlock) ||
                        Collision.playerMovingBlock(new Point(x1 - 2, y1 + 1), movingBlock)) {
                    y = movingBlock.getY() - height - GameState.yOffset;
                    falling = false;
                    topCollision = true;

                    // Move the player the same amount the block is moving
                    GameState.xOffset += movingBlock.getMove();
                } else {
                    if (!topCollision && !jumping) {
                        falling = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void checkBlockCollision(TileBlock[][] tb) {
    // Tile Block Collision
    for (TileBlock[] tileBlocks : tb) {
        for (int x = 0; x < tb[0].length; x++) {
            if (tileBlocks[x].getID() == 1) {

                // Right collision
                if (Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x1, y2 - 2), tileBlocks[x]) ||
                        Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x1, y1 - 1), tileBlocks[x])) {
                    right = false;
                }

                // Left collision
                if (Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x2 - 1, y2 + 2), tileBlocks[x]) ||
                        Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x2 - 1, y1 - 1), tileBlocks[x])) {
                    left = false;
                }

                // Top Collision
                if (Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x2 + 1, y2), tileBlocks[x]) ||
                        Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x1 - 2, y2), tileBlocks[x])) {
                    jumping = false;
                    falling = true;
                }

                // Bottom collision
                if (Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x2 + 2, y1 + 1), tileBlocks[x]) ||
                        Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x1 - 2, y1 + 1), tileBlocks[x])) {
                    y = tileBlocks[x].getY() - height - GameState.yOffset;
                    falling = false;
                    topCollision = true;
                }
                if (!topCollision && !jumping) {
                    falling = true;

                }
            } else if (tileBlocks[x].getID() == 2) {

                // Right collision
                if (Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x1, y2 - 2), tileBlocks[x]) ||
                        Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x1, y1 - 1), tileBlocks[x])) {
                    reachedGoal = true;
                }

                // Left collision
                if (Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x2 - 1, y2 + 2), tileBlocks[x]) ||
                        Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x2 - 1, y1 - 1), tileBlocks[x])) {
                    reachedGoal = true;
                }

                // Top Collision
                if (Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x2 + 1, y2), tileBlocks[x]) ||
                        Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x1 - 2, y2), tileBlocks[x])) {
                    reachedGoal = true;
                }

                // Bottom collision
                if (Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x2 + 2, y1 + 1), tileBlocks[x]) ||
                        Collision.playerBlocked(new Point(x1 - 2, y1 + 1), tileBlocks[x])) {
                    reachedGoal = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The collisions are not registered and the player just falls through the map and out of bounds instead of landing on the blocks on the map, as intended. What is the correct way to extract the method here? All help is appreciated!

Comment: There is too much code here to easily see the diff. You can extract a method by selecting the code you want to extract, and clicking "Refactor > Extract Method".

Comment: By the way: unless you only have 1 player, making `x,y,width,height,reachedGoal` static is a bad idea. Even if you do only have one player, you don't actually need them to be static, and it can be problematic if e.g. you need to restart the game for that one player.

Comment: I tried to extract the methods using "Refactor -> Extract Method" but the player still falls through the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a mistake that may be causing your problem.

### TLDR; Solution

In the already refactored code, you seem to only init your bounding values,
this part :

```
// Bounds for collision
int x1 = (int) (x + width + GameState.xOffset);
int y1 = (int) (y + height + GameState.yOffset);
int x2 = (int) (x + GameState.xOffset);
int y2 = (int) (y + GameState.yOffset);
```

where in the original code you seem to init them every time you go in the `update()` method.
So I believe you only have to move these inits where they belong to make it work.

### Proper way to extract method in latest Intellij

Here is simple way to extract method from any code for Intellij:

- Select code you want to extract
- Right click, and then unfold `Refactor`
- Under `Refactor`, you should see `Extract Method...`, Left click it
- then, you only have to follow the wizard to set method name, every params etc

## EDIT

You added comment while I was responding so, couldn't know you already tried auto method extracting; But first part of my message still remain valid to fix bug